# log4javascript IE8 unexpected error "Function attendue"/"Expected function"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, log4javascript

I'm trying to redirect console calls to log4javascript library.

So basically, any call to `console.log` will call `log.info`, `log` being a Log4javascript instance.

But when it calls `log.info` I get a "Fonction attendue" error (French) which basically means "Function expected".

I also tried to call `log.info` from the IE8 console, same story.

I don't think it's related to the script, but in case of, here it is:

```
(function (fallback) {

    fallback = fallback || function () { };

    // function to trap most of the console functions from the FireBug Console API.
    var trap = function () {
        // create an Array from the arguments Object
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        // console.raw captures the raw args, without converting toString
        console.raw.push(args);
        var message = args.join(' ');
        console.messages.push(message);
        fallback(message);
    };

    // redefine console
    if (typeof console === 'undefined') {
        console = {
            messages: [],
            raw: [],
            dump: function() { return console.messages.join('\n'); },
            log: trap,
            debug: trap,
            info: trap,
            warn: trap,
            error: trap,
            assert: trap,
            clear: function() {
                console.messages.length = 0;
                console.raw.length = 0 ;
            },
            dir: trap,
            dirxml: trap,
            trace: trap,
            group: trap,
            groupCollapsed: trap,
            groupEnd: trap,
            time: trap,
            timeEnd: trap,
            timeStamp: trap,
            profile: trap,
            profileEnd: trap,
            count: trap,
            exception: trap,
            table: trap
        };
    }

})(log.info);
```

I thought Log4Javascript supported IE8, so what's wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log4javascript does support IE 8. The problem is that `this` is incorrect in the call to `log.info`, which expects to be called as a method and hence have a reference to `log` as the value of `this`. I suggest fixing it by passing in the logger object to your IIFE and calling its `info` method:

```
(function (log) {
    var fallback = log ?
            function() {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                log.info.apply(log, args);
            } :
            function() { };

    // function to trap most of the console functions from the FireBug Console API.
    var trap = function () {
        // create an Array from the arguments Object
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        // console.raw captures the raw args, without converting toString
        console.raw.push(args);
        var message = args.join(' ');
        console.messages.push(message);
        fallback(message);
    };

    // redefine console
    if (typeof window.console === 'undefined') {
        window.console = {
            messages: [],
            raw: [],
            dump: function() { return console.messages.join('\n'); },
            log: trap,
            debug: trap,
            info: trap,
            warn: trap,
            error: trap,
            assert: trap,
            clear: function() {
                console.messages.length = 0;
                console.raw.length = 0 ;
            },
            dir: trap,
            dirxml: trap,
            trace: trap,
            group: trap,
            groupCollapsed: trap,
            groupEnd: trap,
            time: trap,
            timeEnd: trap,
            timeStamp: trap,
            profile: trap,
            profileEnd: trap,
            count: trap,
            exception: trap,
            table: trap
        };
    }
})(log);
```

Comment: It may work (can't test it now) but I believe the `apply` function doesn't exist on IE8, as `bind`.

Comment: @Vadorequest: `apply` definitely exists in IE 8. It's been in IE since version 5.5, I think. You're right about `bind` though, that came much later. Standards-wise, `apply` is ECMAScript 3, `bind` is ECMAScript 5.